# Pass function argument as a name of field in $set operator while using findAndModify

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got the following function:

```
module.exports.saveClient = function(name) {
    db.myDatabase.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: 'clients' },
        update: { $set: { clients: { name: {
                                        'name': name,
                                        'projects':{}
                                        }
                }}},
        new: true
    }
};
```

When I call function like this:

```
myModule.saveClient(clientName);
```

in $set operator it read it as:

```
update: { $set: { 'clients': { 'name': {
                                        'name': clientName,
                                        'projects':{}
                                        }
                }}}
```

So name of fields are converted to strings and I want the first 'name' to be 'clientName' (value passed as the argument to my function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put the object property in a variable, then you need to use the **[square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** to construct the field object as follows:

```
module.exports.saveClient = function(name) {
    var clients = {};
    clients[name] = {
        'name': name,
        'projects':{}
    };
    db.myDatabase.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: 'clients' },
        update: { $set: { clients: clients }},
        new: true
    }
};
```

Or using [**computed property names (ES6)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
module.exports.saveClient = function(name) {
    let clients = {
        [name]: {
            'name': name,
            'projects':{}
        }
    }
    db.myDatabase.findAndModify({
        query: { _id: 'clients' },
        update: { $set: { clients: clients } },
        new: true
    }
}
```